# including files into book cover

Tags: packages, book-design, layout, bookcover

I'm hoping this reaches someone who has used the bookcover package before.  I am writing a book as both a physical copy and a pdf.  For the pdf, I created a tex file for the front cover which contains all of its graphics and another tex file for the back cover which contains all of its graphics, which are included in the main file as shown below:

```
\begin{document}

\include{frontcover}

%all other book material

\include{backcover}

\end{document}
```

However, I will also use the bookcover package to create the physical cover:
[image]

Is it possible, using the bookcover package, to do the following, with the spine cover as an image?

```
\usepackage{bookcover}

\include{backcover} \includegraphics{spinecover} \include{frontcover}
```

Or do I need to put those in specifically defined places with specific code?  (I'm using 8.5" x 11" paper.)  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Alternatively, is there a better way to create the entire cover as one large image?

Comment: Note that `\include` introduces a page break before and after the include.  You probably want `\input`, which will act as if the input code is copy/pasted in that spot.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? I heard it was written by somebody who's used that package. At the very least, it should enable you to produce a complete minimal example you can post if you get stuck, but a quick look suggests it has *lots* of information about what you're trying to do, as well as example files.

Comment: I ended up just taking a giant screenshot of the front cover page of the pdf and inputting that image for the front cover of the physical book cover, which was much easier and didn't involve figuring out weird file path issues.